# Google Vision Api Image returns nil

Tags: ios, camera, swift5, google-vision

I am using the the Google Vision API to be able to retrieve the text information from hand writing. I am using the Google Vision coccapod to call that functionality.

I have it set up so where I am able to take a photo and it is able to to run through google vision. The problem is that it always returns a nil when I try to print the text response.

I was wondering if I was calling the functions wrong.

```swift
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        guard let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
            return showAlert(title: "Error", message: "Image not Found")
        }
        takePhotoView.image = image
        let gv = GoogleVision.init(apiKey: "API-KEy")
        
        gv.run(image: takePhotoView.image) { text, error in
            guard let text = text, error == nil else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            print(text)
        }
    
    }
```

This is the image I am trying to have the text read for

[image]

Comment: Did you get any error calling the API?

Comment: Thats the weird thing, I am not getting any error calls when calling the API so been kinda doing this blind. I feel like it is because I set up the api in a wrong way which is why nothing is happening but I cannot pinpoint it